# Which driver is repsonsible for finding UUID in the kernel

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I compiled a custom kernel for myself. I can boot via `root=/dev/mmcblock1p2` but when I try root=UUID="Actual ID" i get a kernel panic. I think I might have not enabled some driver option.

The error is as follows

```
/dev/root: Cant open blockdev
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount rootf on unknown-block(0,0)
```

What kernelconfig option do I have to include to let it boot